# Attach file to sale order in odoo9

Tags: odoo-9

I'm using odoo8 and it has ability to attach a file in sale order such as there:
[image: Attach file to sale order]

What is the addons in odoo9 can do similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attachments List and Document Indexation**